# Writing to a serial port in linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am trying to program a robot that has motordrivers on certain serial ports (i.e. ttyS9)

Through cutecom (as hex input), I can send the following input, which gives me the result I expect:

```
5aaa0700fffff000
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same result with a C program, that does the following:

```
int port9 = open("/dev/ttyS9", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);

char buff[17] = "5aaa0700fffff000";

write(port9, buff, 16);
```

I've also tried to initialize `buff` with the hex values seperately:

```
buff[0] = 0x5;
buff[1] = 0xa;
```

etc etc.

Both do not work. Is the problem in my code, or in the driver?

I compile using gcc and then run it with sudo. The open function also returns values that are proper (no errors), as well as the write.

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. And don't run such code as admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filling a character array with strings will convert characters to their ascii representation not hex as you need.

```
char buff[17] = "5aaa0700fffff000"; // Incorrect for saving 0x5aaa0700fffff000 to buff
```

As i see, you want to write 8 byte 0x5aaa0700fffff000 on serial port, a char is 8bit (1 byte) and you have to send 8 bytes not 16, so the code should be something like this

```
buff[0] = 0x5a;
buff[1] = 0xaa;
...
write(port9, buff, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, I've found that it only works when I have cutecom open, which has ttyS6 or ttyS9 open, and then it works only for these ports respectively. Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: We don't know if OP uses ASCII encoding. And we also don't know if OP uses characters. In fact using a terminal work is an indicator it might be characters.

Comment: @bart-kn - Along the lines of what Olaf is saying... does it work when you manually *type* that sequence from a serial terminal?  And do you have to press `Enter` or `Return` for the the command to work?  If *yes* to both those questions, you might be missing an end-of-line character or characters.  Either `'\r'`, `'\n'` or `"\r\n"`.  If that's the case, you may need to send something like `char buff[18] = "5aaa0700fffff000\n"`.

Comment: @bart-kn - And to add to that thought about the use of newlines (if its an ascii protocol), you should take a look at `man tcsetattr`, in particular, understand `OCRNL` `ONLCR`.  It's good practice to setup the TTY the way you need it to work anyway.

Answer (score -1):

but maybe it's a number
so you'll need 
`unsigned long long int t= 0x5aaa0700fffff000;
write(.., (char *)&t, 8);`

that means byte order in memory is completely different to one you'll  gain with just assigning bytes as you read it from screen.

Comment: ...that will invoke Undefined Behavior...long long int is probably 64 bits long, but surely not 128 bits

Comment: @LPs: `long long` is **at least** 64 bits. It can very well have 128 or more bits.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Olaf I meant: I can bet 1K billion euros that OP `long long int` is `64 bit` long, but I'm sure that isn't `128 bits`. ;)

Comment: @LPs: Please provide a reference to the standard where it disallows that. (if you provide a trusted guareantee you will of the money, I will present you a C compiler with 128 bit `long long`. It actually would make sense on LP64 systems like POSIX. You missed my point: If you want a fixed width interger, use one! The standard provides them.

Comment: @Olaf I can also write an ABI to do so, but I'm really sure that OP is using something standard ;)

Comment: @Olaf It was a joke. I know the `long long int` type is defined to be **at least** 64 bits. And that it can be 128 or whatever, but I'm quite sure OP platform does not natively support 128 bit long long int. BTW Unfortunately I'm Italian.

Comment: @LPs: Problem with too subtle jokes is they may be missunderstood. Considering this is mostly frequented by beginners, I have learned to be very careful and better stick to well defined specs. (and no reason to be sorry being Italian - I more and more feel I'm not from this planet at all ;-) I asked because "standard" and "norm" are perfect false friends in German and English)

Comment: i bet robot will ignore ub chars,or may be it will do somethin exclusive